# How do I access elements of an RCDATA resource?

Tags: c++, winapi

I've been trying to store a few values in an RCDATA resource but I'm not sure how I am supposed to access them individually.

```
HGLOBAL hMem = LoadResource(hInstance,FindResource(hInstance,MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_RCDATA),RT_RCDATA));
PVOID lpData = LockResource(hMem);
```

I "think" I have successfully obtained a pointer to my data but what I'm supposed to do now, I don't know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc194809.aspx is the only information I could find except delphi examples, neither have helped me. My RCDATA is as follows.

```
IDR_RCDATA RCDATA 
{
    10,
    30
}
```

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Such a resource has no structure, it is just a blob of bytes.  It is up to you to write code that imposes a structure.  None is visible in your .rc snippet so the only logical thing is to just read bytes, lpData[index].  SizeOfResource() helps you avoid indexing the blob out of bounds.